# Gitlab import error - SSL (...): unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab.com fails importing a public project from a gitlab-ce installation. The certificate is not self-signed (it is a letsencrypt fresh one).

`Cloning into bare repository '[REPOS PATH]/xxxxx/docker-base.git'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://xxxx.com.br/docker/docker-base.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for this problem (and the only one until now that I've tried and works) is the following (for **GitLab 12.1.3**):

Edit the following file (it is the template file for the *git* configurations for *GitLab*:

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/templates/default/gitconfig.erb
```

Add the following content in the end of the file:

```
[http]
        sslVerify = false
        sslCAPath = /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/
```

Run the command:

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

for *GitLab* assume the changes in the template file and regenerate the file

```
/var/opt/gitlab/.gitconfig
```

---

I've also tried the following but none had worked:

- Adding the certificate to the *trusted-certificates* folder
- Adding the following to *gitlab.rb*: `nginx['ssl_verify_client'] = "off"`
- Adding the following on the *GitLab* machine (this does not work becasue *GitLab* uses *Gitaly*: `git config --global http.sslVerify false`
- Adding the following on the *GitLab* machine (this does not work becasue *GitLab* uses *Gitaly*: `git config --global http.sslCAPath /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/`

References:

- http://blog.mahcsoft.com/?p=7
- https://forum.gitlab.com/t/editing-the-git-configuration-gitconfig-with-custom-settings-gitlab-omnibus/2605